# Actionscript 3: Preventing mouse events *except* for a specific button/movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to block mouse events *except* for a specific MovieClip or Sprite?

i.e. I know that to prevent ALL mouse clicks, I can write something like:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPreventClick, true, 0, true);
...
private function onPreventClick(e:MouseEvent) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check e.[currentTarget](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) to find the object who fired the [`Event`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html) and doing your filtering according to that.